# How can I remove all spaces and punctuation in determining if a word or phrase is a palindrome? (python)

Tags: python, palindrome

I want to know if a word or phrase is a palindrome or not.

I get the correct answer when I type "racecar".

But whenever I type something that includes a punctuation like "Was it a cat I saw?", I get the wrong answer.

This is what I have programmed so far.

Please take a look at and tell me what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
a1=input("Enter a word or phrase: ") 
a=a1.lower()
b=len(a)
c=[]
for i in range(1,b+1):
    d=b-i 
    c.append(a[d])
e="".join(c for c in a1 if c not in ("!",".",":","?"," "))
if e==a:
print (a1,"is a palindrome.")
else:
print (a1,"is not a palindrome.")
```

Comment: You need to debug your program. Try adding `print (e, a)` just before `if a==a` to see what you actually compare

Comment: There is a question mark at the end of the sentence that you are checking? Did you include that in the input?

Comment: Yes, I included question mark in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should normalize the string:

```
s="race. car, "
"".join(x for x in s if x.isalpha())
print s
```

*gives*

```
racecar
```

You can use `s.isalnum` instead to keep numbers in the string

And for the test:

```
if e == e[::-1]: print "palindrome"
```

Comment: I changed my code to e="".join(c for c in a1 if c.isalpha()) but it is still not working..what's wrong with this?

Comment: you are comparing (`e == a`) the string to the original input when instead you want to compare it against its reverse (`e == e[::-1]`)

Answer (score 0):

For the reversal of a string you can use **reverse** method

```
c= a.reverse()
c.replace (' ','')
a.replace(' ','')
If a == c :
    Print ("pallindrome ")
Else :
    Print("not a pallindrome !! )
```

Comment: Are you sure that strings in Python have `reverse` method? I can not find it in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html)

Comment: They don't, neither in the current releases of Python 2 nor Python 3.  What you want if the `reversed` function, as used in my answer, which takes any sequence including a `str`.

Comment: `list`'s have that method. `str`'s don't.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is actually very simple in Python:

```
a = [c for c in input() if c.isalpha()]
if list(reversed(a)) == a:
    print('palindrome')
else:
    print('not palindrome')
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and pass the characters you want to remove as a parameter:

```
import string

s = 'Was it a cat I saw?'
s = s.translate(None, string.punctuation + ' ').lower()
print(s) # wasitacatisaw
```